# Undoing excel default / automatic delimiting

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv

I have a large data export that is going through the end user for spot-checking.
The data was formatted with tab delimiter, as it contains a lot of prices and measurements containing commas.

The problem is that when the user opens the files using excel, excel recognizes  all the commas and helpfully formats the data, incorrectly, as a comma delimited file in stead of a tab delimited file.
As this is an end-user, I don't want to make them format everything manually each time. Especially because excel isn't delimiting the column headers, causing our end user to scratch his head in confusion and drown his sorrows in coffee.

How can I set up the files to make sure that excel does not automatically try and delimit them? Or failing that how can I tell excel to undo the automatic delimiting?